# Oracle concurrent program cannot write to directory

Tags: oracle, rhel

We have an Oracle EBS [concurrent program](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T458253.htm), ran as applmgr, that needs to load data using SQL*Loader, and move the input data to an archive location:

```
sqlldr $w_login \
   control=$w_directory/$w_ctrl \
   data=$w_directory/$w_data \
   log=$w_directory/log/$w_data.log

[[ -f $w_directory/log/$w_data.log ]] && \
   mv $w_directory/$w_data $w_directory/archive/$w_data.archive
```

However, it fails in the `mv` part:

```
34 Rows successfully loaded.
0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

mv: cannot move `/w_directory/w_data.dat' to `/w_directory/archive/w_data.dat.archive': Permission denied
```

The `applmgr` user has write permissions on the directories and file:

```
drwxrwxr-x 14 otheruser othergroup 4096 Apr 16  2012 /w_directory
drwxrwxr-x 14 otheruser othergroup 4096 Apr 16  2012 /w_directory/log
drwxrwxr-x 14 otheruser othergroup 4096 Apr 16  2012 /w_directory/archive
-rwxrwxr-x 14 otheruser othergroup 4096 Apr 16  2012 /w_directory/w_data.dat

$ id applmgr
uid=1003(applmgr) gid=1000(dba) groups=1000(dba),1003(othergroup)
```

We can run the above program manually, through the command-line as `applmgr`, without any issues. But it fails with the above error when ran as a concurrent program. We have already bounced the server as well.

The server is on RHEL 6.4. Oracle EBS is R12.1.3.

Comment: A [concurrent request](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T458253.htm) ran from the EBS web interface, as `applmgr`. The permissions are the same for both scenarios:

    -rwxrwxr-x  1 otheruser othergroup  2422 Apr 21 10:04 /w_directory/w_data.dat

Comment: Thanks... I'm not really familiar with EBS, but to humour me, have you confirmed the script is really running as `applmgr` and not, say `oracle`; who owns a freshly-created log file, for example, or echoing the current user from the script? (I guess they'd still have the permissions they need for the `mv`, or they wouldn't be able to create the log file either, but still...) Submitting something as `applmgr` doesn't mean it executes as them, I think, but not really sure.

Comment: Yes. I dumped some environment variables that the script uses:

    `USER=applmgr
    LOGNAME=applmgr

    applmgr  11667  1761  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /u01/w_script.prog [...]`

I'm not sure what else to check at this point. I even used the full path for `mv`, `unalias`ed it, had the script `touch` a file inside the `archive` directory (didn't work through EBS, worked through the command-line).